# Regular Expression for username and password?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am trying to use a regular expression for name field in the asp.net application.

Conditions:name should be minimum 6 characters ?

I tried the following

```
"^(?=.*\d).{6}$"
```

I m completely new to the regex.Can any one suggest me what must be the regex for such condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Expression library and choose [user name](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=user%20name) and/or [password](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password) regex for you. You can also test your regex in online regex testers like [RegexPlanet.](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html)

My regex suggestions are:

```
 ^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9._\-]{5,}$
```

This regex accepts user names with minimum 6 characters, starting with a letter and containing only letters, numbers and ".","-","_" characters.

Next one:

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-]{6,}$
```

Similar to above, but accepts ".", "-", "_" and 0-9 to be first characters too.

If you want to validate only string length (minimum 6 characters), this simple regex below will be enough:

```
 ^.{6,}$
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use this to match any alphanumeric character in length of 6 or more: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$`. You can tweak it to allow other characters or go the other route and just put in exclusions. The [Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) is a great environment for testing/playing with regular expressions (I [wrote a blog post](http://blog.cymen.org/2009/06/13/regular-expression-tools/) with some links to other tools too).

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
^.{6,}$
```

What's all the stuff at the start of yours, and did you want to limit yourself to digits?

Comment: i don't want to limit to digits ,i just want to limit to the condition: minimum 6(length of the string entered) any string entered less than 6 should cause a validation

Answer (score 1):

[NRegex](http://nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx) is a nice site for testing out regexes.

To just match 6 characters, `".{6}"` is enough

Answer (score 1):

In its simplest form, you can use the following:

```
.{6,}
```

This will match on 6 or more characters and fail on anything less. This will accept ANY character - unicode, ascii, whatever you are running through. If you have more requirements (i.e. only the latin alphabet, must contain a number, etc), the regex would obviously have to change.