# Regular expression for username and password

Tags: regex

Can anyone provide a regular expression for username and password?

> Username: Shouldn't start for digit with minimum 6 character.
>       Password: Alphanumeric with at least 6 character.

There is no upper bound on number of characters though.

Comment: You can find plenty of examples by surfing around, here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665683/regular-expression-for-username-and-password

Comment: @nickhar only if i would understand the expression. Anyway, i did and just didn't find the exact answer.

Comment: There are quite a few regex tutorials and cheat-sheets about, but you didn't ask for an explanation, just a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Username : /\D.{5,}/u
Password : /[a-z0-9]{6,}/i
```

For the username, first get anything that is not a number, than any characters for at least 5 length. For multibyte chars, like **é**, I suggest the *u* modifier. For the password, use alphanumerics and at least 6 of them, and note the *i* modifier for case insensitivity( makes the regex shorter this way ).

Comment: You forgot uppercase chars! [A-Z]

Answer (score 2):

```
for username: \D.{5,}**
for password: .{6,}**
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your request:

**Username:**

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$
```

Broken down:

```
          ^ = Regex starts with
   [a-zA-z] = Only lower and uppercase letter to start
[a-zA-Z0-9] = Alphanumeric
       {6,} = Min of 6 chars and no max (denoted by comma/no-number to follow)
          $ = End of string
```

Thus, this regex accepts usernames with minimum 6 characters, starting with a letter and containing only letters and numbers.

**Password:**

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$
```

Broken down:

```
          ^ = Regex starts with
[a-zA-Z0-9] = Alphanumeric
       {6,} = Min of 6 chars and no max (denoted by comma/no-number to follow)
          $ = End of string
```

This accepts passwords that are alphanumeric and at least 6 characters in length.

You could include other characters in either of these if you wish, eg. to add dashes, underscores, then it's a case of append the chars:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{6,}$
           ^^
```

There are more advanced ways of including non-word chars using character classes, but this should be all you need to get you going.